# Android how to map every next monday and thursday, 6 pm for the next four weeks to actual dates?

Tags: android

My app's user enters a few days from the week, and a few times a day when they need to get notified about something.

So in the SQLite DB I have the following information:

- days of the week the alarm should go off
- hours and minutes of the day the alarm should go off (might be a few times a day)
- number of weeks

Now, how do I get this information and map it to a list of real dates, like June 2nd, 2014 15:30 for example?

Also, for the current week, all the reminders that are already passed, should be moved to the end of the queue.

Comment: How can your user select target date-time? and how your save it in your database?

Comment: they dont select date, they select week days and number of weeks they want to be reminded for. then I save a hashmap with day names and boolean values, an int for the number of weeks and an arraylist<string> with hour/minutes for every day

Comment: Then you have to calculate date by yourself.

Comment: well this is what Im asking - how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have to calculate date by yourself.
Assume 7 day a week. 
For example : Tuesday in next 3 weeks
--> target day should be 7 x 2 + 2 
Use Calendar object, they have method called add(field , value)

Prototype code for above sample:

```
Calendar  c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DAY, 7x2 + 2);
Date date  = c.getTime();
```

then your need object is ***date***
Save this in miliseconds to db and use it later. Done :)

Comment: ok I will take some time to experiment with this and tell you what happened. thanks